# Owl Carousel Not Showing Up With Laravel 5.8 and Bootstrap

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, owl-carousel

I've been trying to set up owl carousel for quite some time now and none of the answers I read seemed to work. So, I began to wonder if it just simply won't work or am I missing something here.

I tried pretty much every possible solution I could find but did not get it to run...

I am using laravel app view with @yield('content') and on the home page I'm inserting the actual content along with the owl carousel.

In the blade.app file I linked all the scripts and css files like so:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/owl.carousel.min.js') }}" defer></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    autoPlay: 1000,
     items:10,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:10
        }
    }
});
    });
</script>


<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/owl.carousel.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/owl.theme.default.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/owl.theme.green.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I load the page noting is showing up. I tried some other bootstrap carousels and they seem to work, but I like this one since it has draggable elements and looks cool...

Here is what it looks like in the editor:
[app.blade.php page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhRvj.png)

[carousel page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsSw5.png)

Comment: Did you get any success on it?

Comment: It is an issue with the Laravel js, try to comment the app.js and test, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the defer and try again by using correct link, may be sometimes the link has to be in incorrect form.